# Open Share/Book mark popup form on normal link

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Share/Bookmark script:

```
<div class="singles-right">
  <a href="#" class="bookmark"></a>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.addinto.com/ai/ai2_bkmk.js"></script>
  <a href="#" class="travels"></a>
  <a href="http://www.addinto.com/ai?type=bkmk" onmouseover="ai2display_bkmk(this, '', '', '');" onmouseout="ai2close_bkmk();" class="share"></a>
</div>
```

but wants to open same email popup if click on **Email Trip to a Friend** link

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i just found

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="ai2display_bkmk(this, 'email','', '');"><img src="http://www.addinto.com/ai/im/email.png" alt="AddInto" border="0" /></a>
```

> thanks to Ashok my designer :)